# Power BI Convert Decimals to Custom Fractions

Tags: excel, powerbi, fractions

I need the summarized values (on charts and tables) to show as a custom fraction.  My organization counts contracts in 13 week incriments.  IE 1 contract = 13 weeks.  If a contract is less or more than 13 weeks then the remaining should show as a fraction. So if we have a contract 5 weeks long, we count that as 5/13.  if it is 14 weeks long we count that as 1 1/13 etc.
 [PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYtyd.jpg)

Example:
I have a chart that sums the contracts and groups them by month. The problem is it's displaying the decimals and not allowing me to use a custom format for the results

Here's a screencast of what is happening [Link](https://www.screencast.com/t/jfbqbuYCK)

In excel we can easily do this by choosing RightClick>Format Cells>Number>Custom> "# #/13" 
 [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh3fg.jpg)

I've attempted to format using DAX and it still won't sum the information. It must be because its not recognizing the field as a number anymore.
[DaxFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKOs.jpg)
[PowerBI2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBOkl.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same custom Excel format strings in DAX using function FORMAT:

```
Custom Fraction = FORMAT ([My Measure], "# #/13")
```

[FORMAT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax)

Edit: 
FORMAT converts numbers to text, so if you want to sum the numbers, you need to do it first, and then format the result. For example, create a DAX measure:

```
 [My Measure] = SUM(Power BI Contracts[Contract])
```

and then use the FORMAT formula as described above.

Comment: thanks for the response! I did exactly that and the Custom Fraction column will not sum.  Maybe because it recognizes it as text instead of a number? I'll add screenshots to the desciption

Comment: In your DAX formula, is [Contracts] a measure, or a column?

Comment: [Contracts] is a column that i've calculated in SQL and brought over to PowerBI

Comment: that's the problem. It has to be a measure, not a column. I will add an edit with an example.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the Custom Fraction Column being summarized in the chart.or table [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/jfbqbuYCK) Here is a screencast of what I'm showing after following those steps